# incomplete type for std::any when GMOCKing interface

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, googlemock

I have a very weird compilation problem with this snippet:

```
#include <any>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>


struct Class
{
    virtual std::any get(int, int) = 0;
};


struct MockClass: Class
{
    MOCK_METHOD2(get, std::any(int, int));
};


int foo()
{
    MockClass dd;
}
```

Error gcc 9.1.0:

```
/usr/include/c++/9.1.0/type_traits:131:12: error: incomplete type ‘std::is_copy_constructible<testing::internal::ReferenceOrValueWrapper<std::any> >’ used in nested name specifier
```

clang 8.0.0:

```
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.1.0/../../../../include/c++/9.1.0/type_traits:132:31: error: no member named 'value' in 'std::is_copy_constructible<testing::internal::ReferenceOrValueWrapper<std::any> >'
```

If I replace `std::any` with `std::string` or any other common type, code compiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is libstdc++ bug [90415](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90415).

I am not sure what it is about `std::any` that causes this problem. Note that your example fails on clang using libstdc++, but succeeds when using libc++.

Answer (score 0):

Additional information about this issue, that I have got a workaround to use `any` with gmock in gcc 9.1.0, use `std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::any` instead of `std::any`, and it works fine.